Where can I see usage (number of requests) for Places API?
I am trying to use free credit from Google and see that I am using 1£ for places API. In order to create limits I'd like to know exactly how many requests my app received, but cannot do it, I can see just the total cost.

To see the number of requests your app received for the Google places API, Go to Google Cloud Console >> Select API & Services Section, In the Console click on this API and Services dashboard, you can see the usage of different APIs and number of requests.
Below Traffic screenshot helps to check the number of requests per day made by or about your project to enabled APIs.  You can refer to this official GCP document on Using the API Dashboard for more details. In the dashboard below you can see the filter for usage of different APIs and number of requests. Lets click on Service Usage API >> Select Quotas And Systems as shown below. 
By using Quotas tab you set limits on the number of requests your project can make to the Maps Platform APIs.Monitoring your API usage is important to manage costs and avoid exceeding your usage limits.
Also try adding an autocomplete widget , which may further help to resolve your issue.
